# How to select data where a field has a min value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I want to select data from a table in MySQL where a specific field has the minimum value, I've tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM pieces WHERE MIN(price)
```

Please any help?

Comment: this question can have multiple interpretation, can you give example records with results?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

this will give you result that has the minimum price on all records.

```
SELECT *
FROM pieces
WHERE price =  ( SELECT MIN(price) FROM pieces )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/954a5/2)

Answer (score 72):

This is how I would do it, assuming I understand the question.

```
SELECT * FROM pieces ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1
```

If you are trying to select multiple rows where each of them may have the same minimum price, then @JohnWoo's answer should suffice.

Basically here we are just ordering the results by the price in ascending order (ASC) and taking the first row of the result.

Comment: Please, tell me, will it work faster than a subquery?

Comment: @YamashiroRion yes of course because it is simple and base query

Comment: But this would fail in case there is any NULL value in the column.

Answer (score 7):

This also works:

```
SELECT
  pieces.*
FROM
  pieces inner join (select min(price) as minprice from pieces) mn
  on pieces.price = mn.minprice
```

(since this version doesn't have a where condition with a subquery, it could be used if you need to UPDATE the table, but if you just need to SELECT i would reccommend to use John Woo solution)

Comment: It looks like it can be reused in a view 

Answer (score 5):

Use **HAVING MIN(...)**

Something like:

```
SELECT MIN(price) AS price, pricegroup
FROM articles_prices
WHERE articleID=10
GROUP BY pricegroup
HAVING MIN(price) > 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

Efficient way (with any number of records):

```
SELECT id, name, MIN(price) FROM (select * from table order by price) as t group by id
```

Comment: I have tried many solutions: using join, using subquery they all are good but consuming more time.

but this one is fabulous.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, depends what you want to get:
- Just the min value:

```
SELECT MIN(price) FROM pieces
```

- A table (multiples rows) whith the min value: Is as John Woo said above.
- But, if can be different rows with same min value, the best is ORDER them from another column, because after or later you will need to do it (starting from John Woo answere):

  SELECT * FROM pieces
  WHERE price =  ( SELECT MIN(price) FROM pieces)
  ORDER BY stock ASC

Answer (score 0):

To improve @sberry's answer, if the column has a `null` value then simply doing `ORDER BY` would select a row with `null` value. Add a `WHERE` clause to get correct results:

```
SELECT * FROM pieces 
WHERE price>0
ORDER BY price ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Or if there is a chance of having negative values and/or `VARCHAR`, etc. do:

```
SELECT * FROM pieces 
WHERE price IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY price ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score -9):

To make it simpler

> SELECT *,MIN(price) FROM prod LIMIT 1

- Put * so it will display the all record of the minimum value

Comment: It actually wouldn't. * will display random values, not necessarily from the row associated with that min.

Comment: Completely agree with Laurentiu L. here: most other DBMS (then MySQL) would not allow you to run such a query without proper `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: This will select a random row to min value and its not what was asked!

Comment: in plus you saw "put * so it display the all record" but you add LIMIT 1 so you will get just one value.