# Left Join query returning wrong row id with correct price

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch the lowest price using left join query by `category_id`. Query returning me correct `price` but different `product_id`.

I have two tables one is `product` and another one is `product_to_category` (using for relation). I'm trying to fetch the `product_id` and `price` which have minimum price using below query.

```
SELECT p.product_id, MIN(p.`price`) FROM oc_product_to_category AS pc 
LEFT JOIN oc_product AS p ON pc.`product_id`=p.`product_id` WHERE pc.`category_id` = 59
```

But above query giving me wrong result, because `category_id=59` contain three `product_id 67, 68, 71`. `67` has price `8` and `71` has `15` price so according `MIN()` it should return the row which contain lowest `price` with same `product_id` but above query giving me lowest price with different `product_id` `71`.  I'm also attaching the tables and result screen shot that you can easily understand. 
**Table oc_product_to_category**

[image]

**Table oc_product**
[image]

**Query Result**

[image]

Can anyone let me know where i'm wrong. I will appreciate. Thanks

Comment: You are using the function MIN on price, that will give you the right price but the product_id will be random.

Comment: @KiwiJuicer Exactly query giving me correct price but `product_id` does not correct I wanted to show same row `product_id`

Comment: Might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357144/mysql-how-to-select-data-where-a-field-has-a-min-value

Comment: `GROUP BY p.product_id`?

Comment: Yes i also think about use group by p.product_id it will give correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MIN` will not work that way. You can try with `ORDER` & 'LIMIT'. Try -

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.`price` 
FROM oc_product_to_category AS pc 
LEFT JOIN oc_product AS p ON pc.`product_id`=p.`product_id` 
WHERE pc.`category_id` = 59
ORDER BY p.`price` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Its working Thanks. I wanted to know your query will be work if i have tow price something like this `8` and 8.10 ?

Comment: Then you have to change the `LIMIT` to `2`.

Comment: I mean if i have two price `8` and `8.10` then your query will be show `8.10` correct ? Thank you for help