# Stuck in building MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, dql

Given an example of table:

```
id | item_id | user_id | bid_price
----------------------------------
```

The task is to select **rows** with **minimum** `bid_price` for each `item_id` in the provided set.

For example: `item_id = [1, 2, 3]` - so I need to select up to three (3) rows, having a minimum `bid_price`.

Example of data:

```
id | item_id | user_id | bid_price
----------------------------------
 1 |    1    |   11    |     1
 2 |    1    |   12    |     2
 3 |    1    |   13    |     3
 4 |    1    |   14    |     1
 5 |    1    |   15    |     4
 6 |    2    |   16    |     2
 7 |    2    |   17    |     1
 8 |    3    |   18    |     2
 9 |    3    |   19    |     3
10 |    3    |   18    |     2
```

Expected result:

```
id | item_id | user_id | bid_price
----------------------------------
 1 |    1    |   11    |     1
 7 |    2    |   17    |     1
 8 |    3    |   18    |     2
```

Actually, I'm using Symfony/Docine DQL, but it will be enough with a plain SQL example.

Comment: Possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357144/mysql-how-to-select-data-where-a-field-has-a-min-value

Comment: 1. In my case the bid_price field can be the same, so need to select only one.
2. I want to select a minimum only within item_id, but not absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the all the columns in the rows you could use a inner join on subselect for min bid price

```
select m.id, m.item_id, m.user_id, m.bid_price
from my_table m 
inner join ( 
select item_id, min(id) min_id,  min(bid_price) min_price
from my_table 
where   item_id IN (1,2,3)
group by item_id 
) t on t.item_id = m.item_id 
   and t.min_price= m.bid_price
   and t.min_id = m.id
```

or  .. if you have some float data type you could use a acst for unsigned

```
  select m.id, m.item_id, m.user_id, cast(m.bid_price as UNSIGNED) 
  from my_table m 
  inner join ( 
  select item_id, min(id) min_id,  min(bid_price) min_price
  from my_table 
  where   item_id IN (1,2,3)
  group by item_id 
  ) t on t.item_id = m.item_id 
     and t.min_price= m.bid_price
     and t.min_id = m.id
```

Comment: This query doesn't fit my needs. It selects more data than needed. If I provice 10 items ids, it should return maximum 10 rows.

Comment: See, I am working with application, that allows to make the same bids, so in practice - there can be similar rows, where only the ID is different. I think your query will select all of them, but I need only one.

And why did you add a limit? I don't need any limits, I am having a set of item_ids. for example you can use item_id IN (1,2,3) - will be ok.

Comment: I have update the answer  using in and not limit  .. hope is what you are  looking for  ..otherwise update your question add  a clear data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Added an example in question. Thanks, your answer is closer to that what I need, but I also want to get only ONE row for item_id. Because the price can be the same for many rows. Thank you in advance!

Comment: looking to your data seems you need  also a min id  (alias just one for each  item_id) answer  updated

Comment: I need only one for each item_id. The user must only be related to the minimum bet_price in the result. The minimum can be selected as MIN(ID) if there are several results. (in practice - there will be a date field for that, of course).

Comment: I use  min(id)  for obtain a single rows  when there is more than one min_price  for user_id.  ..  i have update  the answer with min_id

Comment: I think your query is working for me for 99%. There is a type problem now. The price in the row has a value, for example: 10000. but when you select min(bid_price) it returns 10000.00, and fails because of that. The price column type is float with 2 decimal points. I try to change and FORMAT(t.min_price, 2) = FORMAT(m.PRICE, 2) but this doesn't help me.

Comment: i don't manage  the format for the column so   .im'not changing the content of the data ..

Comment: Please, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491597/mysql-float-type-issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MIN()` with `GROUP BY` in the query:

```
SELECT id, item_id, MIN(bid_price) AS min_bid, user_id 
FROM your_tbl 
GROUP BY item_id 
HAVING item_id in(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: I need to select entire rows. This will not work using your example.

Comment: Your query doesn't return the data I want to get. Yes, it returns the id, itemd_id, user_id and MIN(bid_price), but the MIN(bid_price) is not related to other row data. For example: I know that minimum price is in row with ID: 10, in your case it will have ID: 5, because it have the same item_id, but it doesn't relate with the MIN().

Comment: Will you post your data with expected output?

Comment: I will try to, bet your example still returns wrong data. It does not binds other fields with MIN(). IT takes the first ones, as I explained:
id = 5, item_id = 1, price = 100 AND id = 10, items_id = 1, price = 50 - it will return id = 5, item_id = 1, MIN(price) = 50 - understand? expected id in this case is: 10

Comment: If `item_id=1` for both then my query definitely return row with minimum price. As I have already explained. You have to check your data once. Also its good if you provide your data and desired result

Comment: Added an example in my question. Your query WILL return the minimum price, but it WILL return a WRONG ID. if you will select a row with that ID then you will see that it WILL NOT HAVE minimum price!

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT id, item_id, user_id, min(bid_price) as bid_price 
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY item_id;
```

Comment: AND what is the difference between your answer and mine without no explanations?

Comment: we don't need to use "HAVING item_id in(1,2,3);" according to your answer. There may more than there 3 results

Comment: Have you read comments? OP has specify that he need only selected columns