# Problem in showing the details of the table and their data

Tags: sqlite

So my problem is that I have a table in which I want to print the Minimum price of a book but in the table have 2 books which has the Lowest price so when ever I execute it the output only show me the price for 1 book and the details of the 1 book I want it to show me the 2 books which has the same Lowest price for that I write a query but it's not working can someone help me

```
Select *,Min(price) From Books
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Forpas I didn't understand you

Comment: You tagged both MySql and SQLite. They are 2 different databases. Tag only the 1 that you use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select data where a field has a min value in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357144/how-to-select-data-where-a-field-has-a-min-value-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Min returns the minimum column value. In case you have n identical minimum values you need to do some post processing.

```
SELECT price FROM TABLE Books WHERE price IS NOT NULL ORDER BY price DESC;
```

This will return you the minimum price value in the first row of the resulting DataTable.

Next loop through your result set and check if there are "multiple minimum values".

```
for(int i = 1; i < datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
if( datatable.Rows[i][0] > datatable.Rows[i-1][0] )
{
  this is the first "no match", results with index i = 0 to i - 1 
  have the samevalue
}
```